# After Upgrading Angular from 8 to 10 I got ERROR in ts.updateIdentifier is not a function

Tags: angular, typescript

After Upgrading Angular from 8 to 10
I got

```
 ERROR in ts.updateIdentifier is not a function
```

this is my

ng --version

```
Angular CLI: 10.0.6
Node: 10.15.2
OS: win32 x64

Angular: 10.0.11
... animations, common, compiler, compiler-cli, core, forms
... language-service, platform-browser, platform-browser-dynamic
... router
Ivy Workspace: <error>

Package                           Version
-----------------------------------------------------------
@angular-devkit/architect         0.803.29
@angular-devkit/build-angular     0.803.29
@angular-devkit/build-optimizer   0.803.29
@angular-devkit/build-webpack     0.803.29
@angular-devkit/core              10.0.6
@angular-devkit/schematics        10.0.6
@angular/cdk                      10.1.3
@angular/cli                      10.0.6
@angular/fire                     5.4.2
@angular/http                     7.2.16
@ngtools/webpack                  8.3.29
@schematics/angular               10.0.6
@schematics/update                0.1000.6
rxjs                              6.6.2
typescript                        4.0.2
webpack                           4.39.2
```

I am using yarn , could anyone help me , I am using code-sharing native script

Answer (score 49, accepted):

I ran into the same error today. You should downgrade your typescript dependency to 3.9.7. That fixed it for me.

Comment: for those like me who aren't really familiar with the commands, I used this command and it worked for me: `npm install typescript@">=3.0.0 <3.9.7"`

Comment: Also fixed it for me.  the error occured during the `Compiling @angular/service-worker/config : es2015 as esm2015` step of the build

Comment: Encountered the same issue for `angular 9.x`. I had to downgrade to `typescript 3.8.3`

Answer (score 2):

Since downgrading a major language version was not really an option for me, and I by coincidence had a repository with an angular app that did not have the problem, I compared them to find this solution:

The error existed with `@angular/…` version 10.0.5. When I upgraded these packages to version 10.2.0, the problem was gone.

The full list for my basic app is below, but you might have more `@angular/` prefixed packages:

```
    "@angular/animations": "^10.2.0",
    "@angular/common": "^10.2.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "^10.2.0",
    "@angular/core": "^10.2.0",
    "@angular/forms": "^10.2.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^10.2.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^10.2.0",
    "@angular/router": "^10.2.0"
```