# Why can't I generate an Angular component?

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular, typescript, nativescript

I started a project back in August, I was able to create components just fine. But, now when I try to generate an Angular component I receive this error

```
Option "entryComponent" is deprecated: Since version 9.0.0 with Ivy, entryComponents is no longer necessary.
Cannot read property 'kind' of undefined
```

I'm using Angular 10 and NativeScript 7

```
Angular CLI: 10.1.7
Node: 10.22.0
OS: darwin x64

Angular: 10.1.6
... animations, common, compiler, compiler-cli, core, forms
... platform-browser, platform-browser-dynamic, router
Ivy Workspace: Yes

Package                         Version
---------------------------------------------------------
@angular-devkit/architect       0.1001.7
@angular-devkit/build-angular   0.1001.7
@angular-devkit/core            10.1.7
@angular-devkit/schematics      10.1.7
@angular/cdk                    10.2.5
@angular/cli                    10.1.7
@angular/material               10.2.5
@schematics/angular             10.1.7
@schematics/update              0.1001.7
rxjs                            6.6.3
typescript                      3.9.7
```

Comment: And what else changed since you created the project? Updated the version of Angular, maybe?

Comment: @mbojko I believe the issue is that I updated the NativeScript version. I've found one other person with a similar issue [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64236189/nativescript-error-cannot-read-property-kind-of-undefined-when-run-ng-gener).