# Angular Cli Warning : Option "entryComponent" is deprecated: Since version 9.0.0 with Ivy, entryComponents is no longer necessary

Tags: angular, angular-cli, angular-components

I am using Angular Cli to create component.

I am using this command:

```
ng g c DeviceComponent --module=./views/administration/Accounting.module.ts --spec=false --flat
```

I got the warning :

```
Option "entryComponent" is deprecated: Since version 9.0.0 with Ivy, entryComponents is no longer necessary.
```

and The component does not created
My Angular version is:

```
Angular CLI: 10.2.0
Node: 12.18.3
OS: win32 x64

Angular: 10.2.0
... animations, cli, common, compiler, compiler-cli, core, forms
... language-service, platform-browser, platform-browser-dynamic
... router
Ivy Workspace: Yes

Package                         Version
---------------------------------------------------------
@angular-devkit/architect       0.1000.8
@angular-devkit/build-angular   0.1000.8
@angular-devkit/core            10.0.8
@angular-devkit/schematics      10.2.0
@angular/cdk                    10.2.5
@schematics/angular             10.2.0
@schematics/update              0.1002.0
rxjs                            6.6.3
typescript                      3.9.7
```

I have read this post but it does not help me
[Nativescript error 'Cannot read property 'kind' of undefined' when run 'ng generate component'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64236189/nativescript-error-cannot-read-property-kind-of-undefined-when-run-ng-gener)

I have done

```
 npm install --save-dev typescript@4
```

but it is the same error

Anyone could help me please?

Comment: So you got a warning. Did the component get generated??

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Nativescript error 'Cannot read property 'kind' of undefined' when run 'ng generate component'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64236189/nativescript-error-cannot-read-property-kind-of-undefined-when-run-ng-gener)

Comment: @R.Richards I have edited the question and the answer no

Comment: @Giannis  npm install --save-dev typescript@4 does not help me , the same error

Comment: Angular has an thing it throws errors even it has nothing to do with your new component. Do you have an entryComponent in your app.module.ts and if so try to remove it and then run ur generate command. As your error says its deprecated in version 10 and should be removed ;)

Comment: @Tom I have removed the entry component but the same error

Comment: Hmm any other modules with entryComponents than? Otherwise maybe some cache, but can't remember angular cli caches anything

Comment: @Tom I have a thought like your thinking and I also remove any entry component but the same :(, would you please upvote the question to make more members view the questions  :)

Comment: I have the same error, I can't generate new components and I don't use any entryComponents

Comment: did you solve this problem? then please put the answer @MedhatMahmoud

Answer (score -1):

I think you are using `entryComponent` in one of your module. It was necessary when you were rendering dynamically angular components (modals, popups) in previous versions of Angular.